# I have a react problem that is driving me crazy

Tags: reactjs

I have tested the api and that works and displays how i would like it to but the problem is that when i try to add something as simple as a search bar I am finding that I am struggling. I am trying to learn react and have been enjoying it and hope that someone can point out any errors that they may see as well as the problem i am having. whenever i type and submit into the search bar the console.log(poke) returns two objects containing alot of information, none of which is the value within the textbox. any thoughts would be appreciated as well as any guide or tips for moving forward with react.

```
class Card extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      pokemon: null,
      inputBox: "",

    }

    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    console.log({target})
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }

 async componentDidMount(poke) 
  {
    console.log(poke);
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${poke}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState( {pokemon : data, loading : false} )

  }


    render() {
      return (

        <article className="pokemonStats"
        style={{
          position: 'absolute', left: '50%', top: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
      }}>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.pokemon  ?( 
        <>
        <input name="input" 
        id="first_name"
        type="textbox" 
        name="inputBox"
        placeholder="Enter pokemon here..."
        value={ this.state.inputBox }
        onChange={ this.handleChange }/>

        <button value="send" onClick={this.componentDidMount}>Search</button>
```

Comment: You should not be calling `this.componentDidMount` lifecycle methods like this. Add a function which is called both on `onClick` and on `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount is [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#commonly-used-lifecycle-methods). If you are new to react, try using functional components. Hooks are easier to fathom and easier to work with. You are also generating URL wrong. You are passing click event in URL string, while URL string has to be computed using inputBox state.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card />
    </div>
  );
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      pokemon: null,
      inputBox: ""
    };

    this.getPokemon = this.getPokemon.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }

  async getPokemon(e) {
    try {
      console.log(this.state.inputBox);
      const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.state.inputBox}`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ pokemon: data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <article
        className="pokemonStats"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: "50%",
          top: "50%",
          transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
        }}
      >
        {this.state.pokemon && (
          <span>{JSON.stringify(this.state.pokemon, null, 4)}</span>
        )}
        <input
          name="inputBox"
          id="first_name"
          type="textbox"
          placeholder="Enter pokemon here..."
          value={this.state.inputBox}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

        <button value="send" onClick={this.getPokemon}>
          Search
        </button>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks that has really helped. I will look into hooks now to get a better understanding thanks you very much @gautaits

Comment: I have updated my code @AlexanderKeen. working [sandbox[(https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-silence-g4hu7?file=/src/App.js:0-1620)

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is a lifecycle method which automatically runs after first mount. So you cannot call `this.comopnentDidMount`

```
async setData() 
  {
    const poke = this.state.inputBox
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${poke}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState( {pokemon : data, loading : false} )
  }

  <button value="send" onClick={this.setData}>Search</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution I really appriceate the time you took to help with my problem. @Jagrati

Comment: Should probably point out that `componentDidMount` is no longer an async function and also calls `this.setData()`.